# Bxslider "restart" bug

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bxslider

I'm having a problem with a carousel i've implemented on a site : when going from the last photo to the first one,

- the sliders loops around all photos in the opposite of the usual direction
- after doing that, it flashes the one i started on before going to the first photo.
  here is the HTML :

  ```
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 25px;">
        <div class="bxslider">
            <div><img src="img/diapo1.jpg"></div>
            <div><img src="img/diapo2.jpg"></div>
            <div><img src="img/diapo3.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  ```

And here is the bxslider js :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){ $('.bxslider').bxSlider(); });
```

can anyone help me figure out what's wrong ?
Thanks for helping.

EDIT :

I also have some CSS, to shape the bxslider viewport & images, maybe this cause the issue ??

```
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport, .bx-wrapper img {width: 1100px !important;}
.bx-wrapper, .bx-viewport{height: 450px !important}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction .bx-prev {
    left: 10px !important;
    background-position: auto;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction .bx-next {
    right: 10px !important;
    background-position: auto;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
.bx-next:hover, .bx-prev:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue using the code provided. Perhaps there is some part you have not shared with us?

Answer (score 0):

use bxSlider options...

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true,
  stopAutoOnClick: true,
  pager: true,
  slideWidth: 600
});
```

[Read More about start/stop controls](https://bxslider.com/examples/auto-show-start-stop-controls/)

Comment: using those options doesn't resolve the problem, i also tried using others, though none helped...

Comment: also pager doesn't show, they are present in the page though i can't figure how to have them visible..